# How to place 3 figures arranged in table at two columns of ieee

Tags: floats, ieeetran

How to place 3 figures arranged in a table at two columns as the following:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
%\tabcapfont
\centerline{%
\begin{tabular}{c@{}c@{}c}
\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{fig1.eps} &
\includegraphics[width=1.9in]{fig2.eps} &
\includegraphics[width=1.4in]{fig3.eps} \\
a.~~ Octal linked list & b.~~ Quadratic linked list & c.~~Dual linked list
\end{tabular}}
\caption{The representation of a pixel using linked lists}\label{figure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Use figure* for two column figures (no h option).

Answer (score 2):

For wide floating content (like in your case), set the float using the starred form - `figure*`. This will set it at the top of a the following page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-8]

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c c}
  \includegraphics[width=1.6in]{example-image-a} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.9in]{example-image-a} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{example-image-a} \\
  a.~Subcaption A & b.~Subcaption B & c.~Subcaption C
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

There is very little control over placement of large document elements within a two-column environment, so the above is probably your best option. Moreover, for journal submissions, they will mostly take care of the document structure during editing so that it conforms to other submissions as well.